# Automated bookmark merging/synchronization app/addon between multiple instances of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox concurrently

Tags: web-browser, firefox, chrome, bookmark

Some of my family members prefer Chrome, some prefer Firefox - but either way I use both at least some of the time since as a web developer I really do have to (and MS IE which I hate); All our Firefox installation share bookmarks through Firefox's built in sync which is great. However Chrome doesn't sync with that. So looking for an external program or an addon to one of them to automatically sync/merge with the other

- bookmark merge/sync between FF & Chrome
- Either browser addon or works on Windows

Nice Bonus (not needed but would be nice):

- **option** to merge/sync open windows/tabs
- **option** to merge/sync history
- open source
- cross-platform

Extra really not needed but cool anyways:

- syncing with other browsers (IE, Opera etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) syncs bookmarks, history and open tabs cross browser.

I believe the open tabs sync is a premium feature but the rest is free. You can see more features [here](https://www.xmarks.com/about/features) but it definitely has features you're after. I don't use this any more as I only tend to use Chrome now but I have used it for several years (up until recently)

Comment: Check [XMarks license](https://www.xmarks.com/about/terms) before you start, you might be unpleasantly surprised what you are agreeing with, especially in paragraph **License Grant**.

Comment: Xmarks/Foxmarks works reliable. Firefox sync has messed up my bookmarks once. Xmarks has been working fine (for years) across several browsers/computers.

Comment: Xmarks is TERRIBLE now. Changed hands, TOTALLY messed me up, have NOT recovered and may never. Will take HOURS and DAYS which I don't have. DO NOT USE XMARKS!! And I read that License section - SCARY, total INVASION of privacy, am glad I DELETED Xmarks.