# A tool for managing bookmark sets

Tags: web-browser, bookmark

I have a great collection of various bookmark sets... multiple bookmark files from old Firefox versions, FF at work, at multiple PCs at home, Chrome, IE favorites, plain lists.

I'm looking for a tool that would let me do the following:

*Import/data features:*

- Easily import bookmarks in various formats (All versions of Mozilla FireFox including early ones; Chrome; IE favorites in a directory from various versions)
- Allows me to bulk-add my own bookmarks via a file or pasted list (format is largely irrelevant, as long as it's bulk and not 1 by 1 but ideally should be something simple like CSV and not having to create FF bookmarks file by hand :).
- Supports the concept of folder trees
- Supports the concept of quick link bookmarks, in FF and IE and Chrome
- Supports tag/label metadata if the bookmark source contains it
- Supports metadata of various other sorts (FF bookmarks file typically has tons of metadata per bookmark - timestamps, etc...)

  - Ideally, it should support ANY metadata field, not some pre-set list, but not required.
  - However, the "standard" ones should be stored in "standard" fields, e.g. tags/labels; last-visited or when-added timestamps.
- When you add a new set of bookmarks, automatically **merges** them into current list - this means if the bookmark had any meta data in both old and new set, that metadata is accumulated/merged (labels/tags/timestamps/folder location)

*Output features:*

- Lets me output the bookmarks set in **standard browser** formats (modern FF, IE and Chrome).
- Lets me export entire bookmark DB in some parseable format (Excel, CSV, XML, well formed HTML, SQLite, JSON, whatever). Something I can feed to a script. This is a bit optional but strongly desired.

*Data Management features*.

NOTE: if the last output feature is supported (e.g. I can export 100% of data to something my Perl script can read), I can theoretically live without any of them... if it's not, they are required.

- Ability to filter; and take an action on a filtered set.

  "filter" to me means, select multiple items at once, whether the filter makes the other items disappear from the list or not is not important.
- Filters desided: by tag; by domain; by date; or by substring of URL/title, or ideally by substring of any field in DB.
- Ability to delete all URLs in filtered set
- Ability to add/remove a specific tag from the filtered set
- Ability to move to another folder (again, entire filtered set)

*Optional desired features:*

- Supports automatically re-building the folder tree based on tags.

*Other*

- Price isn't much of an issue but of course gratis prefered.
- OS should be either Windows or Linux.
- Can be a Perl/Python/whatnot import program backed by some standard DB like SQLite, not necessarily a full fledged software.

Comment: Note: I'm NOT looking for syncronization functionality per se ([this Q](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/601/automated-bookmark-merging-synchronization-app-addon-between-multiple-instances) is related but not a dupe)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to what extent this will help  but [this post by Charles Leifer](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/building-bookmarking-service-python-and-phantomjs/) explains beautifully how one can build a bookmarking service with python and phantomjs. You can extract many of the feature to meet your desired preference.

The python script is fairly straightforward, consists of two views, one passes a list of bookmarks to a template for rendering, the other is responsible for adding new bookmarks.