# Sync / merge Firefox bookmarks with skipping duplicates html/json (open-source)

Tags: linux, open-source, web-browser, firefox, bookmark

I want a tool to merge bookmarks (bookmarks files as stored in FF profile) from two places (PCs) from time to time, in automated way, having Linux terminal / CLI option (I don't want to select files in GUI each time), open-source copyleft licensed. Answers found via web search mostly advice to use [sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/), but it requires to agree to Terms of Service, which is IMO burdensome, as I can live with moving bookmarks via local html / json files.

After I wrote the above SE found several related posts: [A tool for managing bookmark sets](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/a-tool-for-managing-bookmark-sets), [Syncing Firefox and Google Chrome Browser Bookmarks](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/syncing-firefox-and-google-chrome-browser-bookmarks), [Automated bookmark merging/synchronization app/addon between multiple instances of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox concurrently](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/601/automated-bookmark-merging-synchronization-app-addon-between-multiple-instances). I've looked at them and the answer about Python https://charlesleifer.com/blog/building-bookmarking-service-python-and-phantomjs/ is IMO worth reading about more.

However, most of posts are several years old, maybe there are new solutions and also, my current task is to sync only Firefox boookmarks, therefore same format (I expect it to be, though FF versions might be slightly different).

Comment: Would a direct sync via browser addons be an option, too? Asking because you exlicitly mentioned CLI as requirement. If a browser addon would be OK, there's e.g. [Floccus](https://floccus.org/) working with Nextcloud Bookmarks, WebDAV, GDrive and others. Not sure if it meets your requirements (I haven't used it myself yet), hence just a comment. And yes, [Floccus is FOSS](https://github.com/floccusaddon/floccus) ;)

Comment: @Izzy, thank you! I'm looking into it. Learning to set up my own server (Nextcloud) was one of things I considered interesting, but have not managed to do. Now maybe my next opportunity and motivation.